# Overriding Back Verbiage on Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

In Swift, how does one override default behavior for the back button that comes with the navigation bar.  Currently, the back button behavior is to provide the left-facing chevron and then the title of the previous tableview in the stack (if it will fit on the nav bar).  However, I prefer that it always say "Back" regardless of the whether the previous tableview's title will fit on the bar or not.  As illustration:

[image]

In the pic above I'd like for the "Genre Fiction" to be replaced with "Back".

Answer (score 0):

in storyboard, go to the view controller that you are wanting to go back to. click "navigation item"  in the view hierarchy, and go to the inspector/attributes panel and change the "back button" entry to just "Back"

Comment: The navigation controller is not an element in the storyboard.  It is added programatically.